# Which RAM should I add to my laptop with processor 2133 MHz speed...?

Tags: laptop, processor, memory, upgrade

Actually, I want to upgrade my laptop RAM. So, when I was searching for compatible RAM for my laptop I got to know that it was already pre-installed(inbuilt) with 4GB 2666 MHz? Do I need to add 8GB of 2400 MHz or 2666MHz?

**Specifications**

**-->Motherboard : 832A**

**-->Processor : Intel core i5 7200U (7th gen)**

**-->Motherboard Clock speed ranges from 2400-2666 MT/s**

**-->Processor supports DDR4-2133.**

Comment: Though slower RAM *might* work -- or might not, why not use the same as already installed?

Comment: Based on an LTT video, RAM memory with the same speed, timing and capacity can mostly be mixed within the same computer.

Comment: [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Comment: @Irsu85 what does mean LTT video..?

Comment: An LTT video is a video made by Linus Tech Tips

Answer (score 0):

For your information :
Faster RAM can work but will be limited by existing memory's speed.

Go for 2666 DDR4 like the one installed in your machine in order to avoid slowing down to 2400MHz.